# Sum a column or another based on a helper column - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, looker-studio

I'm using Google Data Studio, and have 12 columns, 1 per month, with numbers, and another column with dates. I'd like to `SUM` all the numbers that will fall inside a date range based on the date column.

So I've something like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  DATE   | January | February | March  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|20180101 | 500     |         |         |
|20180203 | 150     |         |         |
|20180201 |         | 100     |         |
|20180301 |         |         | 200     |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

I'd like to have `650` as the result from January extraction, but can't find a solution yet.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for aggregation?

```
select sum(january)
from t
where date >= :datestart and date < :dateend
```